# PYSPARK: how can I update a value in a column based in a condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Given a table with two columns: DEVICEID and DEVICETYPE

How can I update column DEVICETYPE if the string length in DEVICEID is 5:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.where(length(col("DEVICEID")) = 5).show()
```

Comment: `df.withColumn('DEVICEID',when(col('DEVICEID')=5,updated_value).otherwise(col('DEVICEID'))` ... something like this?

Comment: I need to update DEVICETYPE column when the length in DEVICEID is 5, it is giving me a syntax error, I am also trying df.withColumn('DEVICETYPE',when(col('DEVICEID')=5,updated_value).otherwise(col('DEVICEID'))

Comment: NP, it is better to read docs when someone comments a code to get a clearer picture(IMO) :) Happy coding

Comment: Happy coding 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`when+otherwise`** statement and check the length of `deviceid==5` update new value.

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([('abcde',1),('abc',2)],["DEVICEID","DEVICETYPE"])

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("new_col",when(length(col("deviceid")) ==5,lit("new_length")).otherwise(col("DEVICEID"))).show()
#+--------+----------+----------+
#|DEVICEID|DEVICETYPE|   new_col|
#+--------+----------+----------+
#|   abcde|         1|new_length|
#|     abc|         2|       abc|
#+--------+----------+----------+
```